# PostGIS - find intersections in space and time

Tags: postgresql, gps, postgis

I store GPS tracks in Postgres with PostGIS and would like to find intersections between them not just in space but also in time. I'm thinking of using 3D geometry but treat 3rd coordinate as time. Basically as soon as new data comes I insert POINT(lat, lon, t) into a GPS track. To find intersections I make a query to find nearby objects along the path (a LINESTRING).

Based on what I know about PostGIS and spatial indexes it should work just fine. From the other side this kind of unorthodox usage of a spatial coordinate makes me a bit nervous. Is it ok to use PostGIS this way or there are better way to do what I want?

Comment: There is nothing *inherently wrong* with unorthodox solutions, but being "a bit nervous" is also appropriate. Two issues tend to come up in unorthodox solutions. **Insufficient testing**, especially of edge cases (what happens if t<0) and keep test cases for regression testing later. **Insufficient documentation**. Make sure an accomplished author/tech writer does that and that it on its. I.E. understood by the most junior developer you can find without you explaining any of it.

Comment: @Belayer completely agree, what I'm trying to do here is to maybe find someone who did similar thing and report their experience. This hopefully save me and others ton of time.